# Should this question be reopened? "How should I get started programming Android"

Tags: discussion, support

There are many questions that ask (in one way or another) how to get started programming Android such as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2869338/328397

The problem is that all the questions have been "merged" & closed, where I can't find the unmerged, open, on-topic one.  Where is the "master" question I should refer to?

Furthermore, there are so many closed questions that relate to class of question, I would be hesitant to ask "how do I get started with technology xyz".  I struggle to find one that is open and not off topic.    Are those series of questions of this nature generally off topic?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475152/how-can-i-learn-android

Comment: Should it be reopened?  No, but it should be deleted.  Only two more...

Comment: @jeff yeah, that question won't be a problem.

Comment: We get lots of questions like this.  There are many more still lurking unclosed in the history of asked questions.  They should be hunted down, stalked relentlessly until they break down sobbing, and then summarily shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many questions about "How do I start learning X?", not just Android.  There is no master, on-topic post for questions in that line.  The answer is "google X tutorial," and we aren't here to post LMGTFY links.